# Java Draw Line based on doubles (sub-pixel precision)

Tags: java, swing

I am making a basic Java program and I would like to draw a line using basic swing [Graphics.drawLine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Is there a way to make the two points in terms of doubles so I can make the output more accurate, or another way that is better?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can draw the lines using `((Graphics2D) g).draw(Shape)` and pass it a `Line2D.Double`.

Here's a demo:

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTestBase extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FrameTestBase t = new FrameTestBase();
        t.add(new JComponent() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    double delta = i / 10.0;
                    double y = 5 + 5*i;
                    Shape l = new Line2D.Double(5, y, 200, y + delta);
                    g2.draw(l);
                }
            }
        });

        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setSize(400, 400);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You might also want to try adding

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE)
```

Comment: @aioobe why so convoluted answer while simple 1 line was enough?

Comment: @ringbearer, because a future googler / visitor should quickly and easily be able to tell whether or not this answer suits their needs. For graphics related questions and answers, a screen-shot is usually the best way to illustrate what problem the answer solves.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, this hasn't made any difference. It only works if you combine it with `g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE)`. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415640/is-there-any-way-to-draw-lines-with-subpixel-precision-in-swing

Answer (score 15):

If you have a refernce to `g`, which I assume is `Graphics` object, you should use Java 2D APIs

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
```

Javadocs for:

- [Line2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html)
- [Graphics2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)